# How to fetch data from database in static class

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to fetch data from from data database in static class. But it shows some error. My code is like this:

```
<?php
class User_training
{
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "DB");
    print_r($con);     

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM training WHERE id=3");
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
}

?>
```

suggest some method to do this.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You will want to take a look at the manual regarding classes and OOP. You need methods (class functions) that wrap your script(s): http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: where is your code?